Casting foreign key in EF Core
I have a pair of related objects that are being tied through a secondary key that don't have the same type and I am trying to relate the objects together.
In essence I have something like:
public class A 
{
    Guid PK { get; set; }

    // is an internal and external key so generically typed
    string ReferenceKey { get; set; } 
  
    ICollection<B> RelatedClassBObjs {get;set;} // this can be null
}

public class B 
{
    int Key { get; set }

    A RelatedClassAObj { get; set; }
}

Class A's ReferenceKey is sometimes a reference to Class B's Key and so is an int, but in other times it can be an external reference and so could be anything from a GUID to a random string.
I'm attempting to relate the 2 classes using Fluent API doing something like
modelBuilder.Entity<B>(entity => {
  ... //Property set up omitted 
  entity.HasOne(e => e.RelatedClassAObj)
   .WithMany(d=>d.RelatedClassBObjs)
   .HasForeignKey(e=>e.Key)
   .HasPrincipalKey(d => d.ReferenceKey);
});

And I have the alternate key set up for Class A as well
modelBuilder.Entity<A>(entity => {
  entity.HasKey(e => e.PK)
    .HasName("PRIMARY");
  entity.HasAlternateKey(e => e.ReferenceKey )
    .HasName("reference_key");
  ... // extra setup omitted 
});

With this setup the join SQL generated looks like
JOIN B b ON b.Key = a.ReferenceKey 

However this seems to be attempting to cast/read the string ReferenceKey as an integer and then blows up when there is a non-integer present. In the SQL this seems to be able to be fixed by adding a cast to string around the b.Key
JOIN B b ON CAST(b.Key as string) = a.ReferenceKey 

But I cannot figure out a way to get fluent API to do this. I have no control over the Data bases, nor over the Linq queries (the model is being used by HotChocolate so I do not have direct Linq/SQL control).
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Honestly I don't what you have here is a foreign key relationship. You won't be able to put square pegs in round holes here...

Sounds horrific. Relate the two properly using a pair of same typed columns, then provide another lookup column on the relevant entity, to use for your lookup/ external id/guid/horoscope

To add a little more detail to my thoughts, ... unless you are using some kind of database such as sqlite or maybe duckdb or something I haven't heard of ... databases will require type compatibility for foreign key relationships. You could not for example in SQL Server have a foreign key from an integer column to a string column (nor could EF ever create such a mapping or such a foreign key constraint since its not possible on the DB side). You will probably have to do your queries without creating foreign keys.

Or perhaps you may like to provide some sample data that could reproduce your classes and some examples of these object that have different kinds of "relationships" where sometimes a "reference key" matches an "int id" and other times matches other things.

Also for what its worth (I may be wrong) but if you have no control over the database side, then you really should not be trying to create foreign relationships if they don't exist on the DB side. Or in other words, if the DB does not have this foreign key in it, you don't want to tell EF Core that it is there (since it isn't).

I hear your comments and I do generally agree, this situation is a bit of an oddity. The setup here is that the two tables are in two separate databases and are for separate products that talk to each other owned by the same company. Copies of these two databases are being brought together through a data lake service so that we can do a lot of interrelated lookups between tables in various databases. My service can only talk to the data lake, hence why I don't have control over the databases. There are some DB changes I could do but they would be painful so I wanted to check this path first.
